# Python, how to loop through whole list

Tags: python, for-loop, continue

I'm creating a text adventure game and when examining objects instead of lots of if statements

for example - If word in list and location = room  then print description,

I thought I would loop through a list and only have one If statement as below.

If the location = 1, I can type door or mat and get descriptions.
but if the location = 2, the second door description won't come up.

How do I get the code to loop through the whole list and print the description of the door at location 2 ? Thanks for your help.

```
list_of_objects =[
    "door","A sturdy door that is firmly locked.",1,
    "door","A test door. Why do I never appear?",2,
    "mat","Its one of those brown bristly door mats.",1]
location = 1
word = ""

def print_description():
    for x in list_of_objects:
        if x == word and location == list_of_objects[list_of_objects.index(word)+2]:
            print(list_of_objects[list_of_objects.index(word)+1])
            return
    print("Sorry, what was that ?  ")

while word != "x":
    word = input("Type door or mat  ")
    print_description()
```

Comment: You're looking for a dictionary

Comment: Make it a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Use a dictionary or tuple as described in user4815162342 's answer because the second part of your if statement `list_of_objects[list_of_objects.index(word)+2]` will always be 1 for door. `index(word)` will only consider the first appearance of `word`, in this case the first index. You can check this by adding prints, or debug the code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a flat list of object properties one after the other, you should have each list member fully describe the object. For example, you can populate the list with tuples:

```
list_of_objects = [
    ("door", "A sturdy door that is firmly locked.", 1),
    ("door", "A test door. Why do I never appear?", 2),
    ("mat", "Its one of those brown bristly door mats.", 1)
]
```

Then you can examine it using:

```
def print_description(user_word, user_location):
    for object_type, description, location in list_of_objects:
        if object_type == user_word and location == user_location:
            print(description)
```

Another option is to use dicts instead of tuples as list members. This is a bit more typing at first, but it makes it easier to add more properties later, as well as include optional properties.

```
list_of_objects = [
    { "type": "door",
      "description": "A sturdy door that is firmly locked.",
      "location": 1 },
    ...
]
```

Comment: A list of dictionaries would be even better, IMHO.

Comment: @Barmar Agreed in general, but for very short individual items, a tuple is shorter to write and easier to unpack. Triples, as shown here, are probably still reasonable, but for more than that I'd go for a dict.

Comment: @Barmar That's a good point (and a very real problem with using tuples like I did here in production code). I've now included it in the answer.

Comment: Named tuples are a good tool for this as well. For homogeneous data they have the advantages of both meaningful addressing and performance+immutability of tuples. Just be sure to always address them through names and not index for extensibility

Comment: There's a much more natural and efficient way to do this - see my posted solution.  It's also trivial to dynamically add or remove keys, or change the associated values.  Using a list is the wrong approach.

Comment: @TomKarzes Your solution is better suited for `print_description`, but we don't know that a lookup of (type, location) is the only thing the OP will use the list for. A general list of (named)tuples/dicts also has the advantage of being able to accomodate properties other than description.

Comment: The dict solution can accommodate multiple properties just as easily as the list - simply replace the description with a list or tuple or whatever you like.  And you can iterate over the key/value pairs of a dict just as easily as you can iterate over the entries in a list.  So again, I'm not seeing any disadvantage whatsoever.

Comment: @TomKarzes Your solution moves part of the object properties into the key. It is not true that it is as convenient to iterate over key/values as it is over just values, especially if the values are themselves dicts of properties (or objects describing them). If more properties are needed, I would go for a separate list of objects and build the indexes (such as your <type, location> -> obj index) as needed by the code.

Comment: I don't see it that way at all.  All OP needs is a way to get the description from a word and a location.  I really don't think there's a need to search for all references to a given description, which seems to be what you suggest.  And what you may not realize is that you're proposing a linear-time solution to a problem that has a constant-time solution.  Do you think a compiler uses an array search for its symbol table?  Of course not, it uses a hash table.  They are tailor-made for problems just like this.

Comment: @TomKarzes Let me assure you that I realize that a list scan is not constant time, unlike a dict lookup. :) The answer was in response to a question titled "how to loop through whole list". The analogy with the compiler is irrelevant because we don't know what the *whole* OP's use case entails, and extended discussion on this issue is pointless for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use a dict whose keys are word, location pairs (tuples):

```
dict_of_objects = {
    ("door", 1): "A sturdy door that is firmly locked.",
    ("door", 2): "A test door. Why do I never appear?",
    ("mat",  1): "Its one of those brown bristly door mats."
}
```

Then all you need is:

```
def print_description():
    key = word, location
    if key in dict_of_objects:
        print(dict_of_objects[key])
    else:
        print("Sorry, what was that ?  ")
```

This way there's no need to iterate.